# How do I take a value entered into a form, redirect to a page a php page that can retrieve that variable?

Tags: php, forms

I have two pieces I need to connect together

1) A simple HTML form that collects a website url

2) A PHP script that receives the url entered from the form.

I have the PHP script finished but it only works if I hard-code the url value within the PHP script.  I don't understand how to transfer the url value from the html form to the PHP script.

This is the form:

```
<form id="dm" class="api"  method="post" action="apigenerate.php">
  <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="710370" />
  <input class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is the API Script, on the 6th line is where the input value needs to go

```
<?php
$data = '
{   
"site_data":
{                       
" the form input goes here "
}
}
';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.servername.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:Ypassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
```

Comment: you can write an API but not a html form\php handler? (form,input,submit,$_POST\$_GET ..)

Comment: you are nice... I was given sample code and I only know some basic php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be helpful to see what you've done so far, but traditionally you would do something like this:

HTML

```
<form action=myscript.php method=POST>
   <input type=text name=websiteUrl />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
   $url = $_POST['websiteUrl'];
?>
```

Comment: Thank, I did not think realize asking a simple question was so insulting to these other people